# Java efficient search algorithm for complex strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I have list of food products stored in database. When user type product name i want to show him for example list 20 best matching items. Data base has about 300 - 400 entries.

I tried implementation of Levenshtein distance but when i type **"vanilla"** algorithm return same result for **"Basil, fresh"** and **"Vanilla extract"**, user should see only second string i need some more accurate algorithm.

Comment: you might consider using a data structure to solve your problem. I think a `trie` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which is typically used to implement spell checkers, could do this. First prepare it by populating it with your dictionary (food products) - each path from root to leaf represents an separate product. Then as the user types, attempt to traverse down the tree - at any given node you can make predictions (and offer suggestions) by examining the possible paths down to the leaves.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand it clearly but when user will type just **"Extract"** instead of **"Vanilla extract"** he wont find vanilla or any other extracts. Application will just show possible ways to leaf while user will be typing next letters in the correct order, right?

Comment: You can implement `trie` data structure, it is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data-structures/7178/trie-prefix-tree-radix-tree#t=201610022013299177137)